# how to move a member to a different channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have been looking around how to make a command to move someone to a different channel but they use a command called .setVoiceChannel but I can't find it? I know think might be kind of a noob question.

here is what I currently have

```
const user = message.author.id;
const member = message.guild.member(user);

// what a I trying to do
member.setVoiceChannel(/* them parameters */); // not defined and I can't find it in documents
```

Comment: It's probably a custom defined method. It doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// The member is the message author.
const member = message.member;
// Getting the channel.
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("Channel");

// Checking if the channel exists and if the channel is a voice channel.
if (!channel || channel.type !== "voice") return console.log("Invalid channel");
// Checking if the member is in a voice channel.
if (!member.voice.channel) return console.log("The member is not in a voice channel.");

// Moving the member.
member.voice.setChannel(channel).catch(e => console.error(`Couldn't move the user. | ${e}`));
```

---

Note: [setVoiceChannel()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setVoiceChannel) is a valid method of `GuildMember` in Discord JS v11.

It has been changed to `GuildMember.voice.setChannel(ChannelResolvable)` in Discord JS v12.

Comment: Thanks you so much!